# Report Formulas - Divide Summary Field by Number of Users

Tags: reporting, custom-reports, function

I am trying to find the Average Number of Hours each user logs per week (by Billable vs Non-Billable Hours). I have attached a screenshot.

I want the sum of the hours (20.34) divided by the number of users who have logged hours (in this case 9). But the number of users is a moving target and different each week.

Next to the Users name it says the number of records. 1 record = 1 logged time frame. Every option I have tried ends up finding the average amount of time logged per record, not per user.

I have tried the Power of 1, but that didn't seem to help and still found the average amount of time logged per record.

I think maybe I should go down the PARENTGROUPVAL rabbit hole but have never used that function before (even confirmation this is the right path to take would be appreciated).

Any feedback or potential solutions is appreciated.

Thanks!

[image]